# What would Alexius Meinong have thought about this Mark Twain witticism?

Tags: ontology

Consider the following Mark Twain witticism:

> I do not fear death. I had been dead for billions and billions of years before I was born [sic], and had not suffered the slightest inconvenience from it.

Alexius Meinong thought a lot about void mechanics, that is, the metaphysics of the relationship of existence to non-existence. What would he have thought about Mark Twain's remark that he didn't mind (which presupposes existence, *cogito ergo sum*) the time he spent not existing prior to birth?

Comment: i would have thought of death and non-birth as states of a person.

Comment: This is a misquote, a later invention attributed to Mark Twain.